# Lists in python with mapping with each other element

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, numpy, anaconda

I have a list like this : ['A,'B','C'] and I want output like this

```
['AB','BC','CA']
```

How can I get this output . Any help appreciated . I am getting the input list as the iteration from a for loop. Thanks

Comment: What output do you want for `['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care about the order between and within pairs:

```
import itertools
list(map(''.join, itertools.combinations(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], 2)))
['AB', 'AC', 'AD', 'BC', 'BD', 'CD']
```

If you do care:

```
L = list('ABXD')
N = len(L)
[L[i] + L[(i+d) % N] for d in range(1, N//2 + 1) for i in range(N if 2*d < N else d)]
['AB', 'BX', 'XD', 'DA', 'AX', 'BD']
```

To make the logic of this a bit more transparent here are the answers for `[], ['A'], ['A', 'B'], ... ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F']`:

```
[]
[]
['AB']
['AB', 'BC', 'CA']
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DA', 'AC', 'BD']
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EA', 'AC', 'BD', 'CE', 'DA', 'EB']
['AB', 'BC', 'CD', 'DE', 'EF', 'FA', 'AC', 'BD', 'CE', 'DF', 'EA', 'FB', 'AD', 'BE', 'CF']
```

Comment: Works well, How can I get this: ['ABC','ABD','ABE','BCD','BCE', 'CDE'] from a list of ['A','B','C','D','E'] Any help appreciated, Thank You so much

Comment: @Ara Don't you want for example `'ACD'` in that list?

Comment: I got it, Thank YOu so much :)

Comment: Yes I needed, I just used 3 in place of 2

Comment: Hi, I have a list like this   ['AC', 'AF', 'CF'] ,I want the output to be [A,C,F]         
 For example input is :   ['AC', 'AD', 'CD'], I want output as [A,C,D] .What is an understandable way to get it. TIA

Comment: @Ara `sorted(set(''.join(L)))` where `L` is your input list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` with list comprehension, note `lst[1:] + lst[:1]` is used to roll the list by one element:

```
lst = ['A','B','C']
[x + y for x, y in zip(lst, lst[1:] + lst[:1])]
# ['AB', 'BC', 'CA']
```

​

Comment: @Jeronimo but OP is asking for _"with each other element"_, so arguably except for n=0 and n=3 this (and most other answers) gives wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

fully lazy version using the great [more-itertools](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/more-itertools) package

```
import itertools
from more_itertools import pairwise

def wrapped_pairwise(it):
    it = iter(it)
    try:
        element = next(it)
    except StopIteration:
        return iter(())
    return (a+b for a, b in pairwise(itertools.chain((element,), it, (element,))))

assert list(wrapped_pairwise("")) == []
assert list(wrapped_pairwise("A")) == ["AA"]
assert list(wrapped_pairwise("ABC")) == ["AB","BC","CA"]
assert list(wrapped_pairwise(["A","B","C"])) == ["AB","BC","CA"]
```